# Setting a Variable to a Switch's Result

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

In C#, is there a way to set a variable from a switch expression?  For example:

```
var a = switch(b)
{
    case c:
    d;

    case e:
    f;

    default:
    g;
};
```

Is it possible in any other language?

Comment: `switch(b) { case c: a = d; case e: a = f; default: a = g;}`

Answer (score 135, accepted):

**From C# 8 onwards:**

Yes, *switch expressions* were introduced in C# 8. In terms of syntax, the example would be:

```cs
var a = b switch
{
    c => d,
    e => f,
    _ => g
};
```

... where `c` and `e` would have to be valid *patterns* to match against `b`.  `_` represents the default case.

**Before C# 8:**

No, `switch` is a statement rather than an expression which can be evaluated.

Of course, you can extract it into another method:

```
int x = DoSwitch(y);

...

private int DoSwitch(int y)
{
    switch (y)
    {
        case 0: return 10;
        case 1: return 20;
        default: return 5;
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `Dictionary` if it's just a case of simple, constant mappings. If you can give us more information about what you're trying to achieve, we can probably help you work out the most idiomatic way of getting there.

Comment: Nope, I can certainly figure it out in a million ways, I just had the a = whatever in each statement and thought I had seen this happen. Guess not. Oh, well. No big deal.

Comment: It is possible now to set a variable to a switch result since c# 8.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58720083/1185067 for example.

Comment: @VladislavStelmakh: Yes, this is one of the downsides of having written nearly 35,000 answers - I can't go through and update them all every time new features come out...

Comment: Any way to utilize switch expressions without returning a value?  In my case, I wanted to switch on file extensions that call a particular method that returns void.

Comment: @ScubaSteve: No, just use a switch statement in that case.

Comment: I like to think that the C# team saw this question and said "that's an awesome idea: we should do that!"

Comment: @AlexfromJitbit: That's a pretty serious accusation. While obviously this was now over 2 years ago, I doubt that I copied and pasted anyone's answer. Yes, Vladislav reminded my of this Q&A in a comment, I see no evidence that I copied and pasted their answer - I really wouldn't have to, given how utterly trivial it is to convert the switch statement in the question into a switch expression. Note that Vladislav's own answer claims that `c` and `e` "should be constants", my own answer indicates that they need to be valid *patterns* (not necessarily constants).

Comment: @JonSkeet I deleted my previous comment and I do owe you an apology. I was reviewing the edit history, and for some reason I was under the impression you edited someone else's answer. While you were in fact, editing your own. Gee, apologies for that. Sorry. My initial comment is completely irrelevant. Apologies again

Answer (score 18):

No, you can't use a switch statement as an expression. Another way to write it is nested conditional operators:

```
var a = b == c ? d:
        b == e ? f:
                 g;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is not possible in C#.

The closest would be to either move this into a method, or do the assignment in each case individual, ie:

```
int a;
switch(b)
{
 case c:
     a = d; break;
 case e:
     a = f; break;
 default:
     a = g; break;
};
```

> Is it possible in any other language?

Yes.  For example, most functional languages support something similar.  For example, F#'s [pattern matching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) provides a (much more powerful) version of this.

Answer (score 6):

If you weren't especially concerned about efficiency, it would be pretty easy to cook up a little class using generics that allowed you to use a "fluent" chain of method calls such as this:

```
var a=Switch(b).Case(c).Then(d).Case(e).Then(f).Default(g);
```

or, if you prefer, the more compact

```
var a=Switch(b).Case(c, d).Case(e, f).Default(g);
```

If this interests you, I'd be happy to cook up an example

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334138/combine-return-and-switch/3334876#3334876)

Comment: ...though I do think your implementation can be simplified... you can do it with immutable data structures, and there's no need to maintain a dictionary. I might comment on that other thread if you don't mind :-)

Comment: Can I accept multiple answers? This one is awesome enough to count, IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

I just wanted to add that Jon Skeet's answer here will not compile and result in an error, since the C#8 switch assignment needs to be closed off with a semicolon.

```
var a = b switch
{
    c => d,
    e => f,
    _ => g
}; //<-- here
```

/I am lacking the reputation to comment this under his answer, but since his is the top answer, it should be noted./

I edited the answer in question now

Answer (score 4):

`switch` in C# is a statement that doesn't have a "return" value. If you're interested in having a "switch" expression, you can find the little fluent class that I wrote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334138/combine-return-and-switch/3334876#3334876) in order to have code like this:

```
a = Switch.On(b)
  .Case(c).Then(d)
  .Case(e).Then(f)
  .Default(g);
```

You could go one step further and generalize this even more with function parameters to the `Then` methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it since [c# 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#switch-expressions), it is called "Switch expressions":

```
const int c = 1;
int d = 2;
const int e = 3;
int f = 4;
int g = 5;

int b = 3;

var a = b switch
{
    c => d,
    e => f,
    _ => g,
};

Console.WriteLine(a);
```

`a` will contain value 4

`c` and `e` should be constants as per switch syntax, `_` corresponds to the default switch branch

Comment: I like to think that Microsoft found my post and thought "this is a good idea" and implemented it :)

Comment: This is true, but switching from c#7 to c#8 will introduce nullable reference types, and it's a breaking change for existing code bases, so beware !

Comment: @dsharpe, nullable reference types are an opt-in feature and should be explicitly configured using <Nullable> tag in csproj or compiler directives such as #nullable enable / #nullable restore

Answer (score 1):

No.

A `switch` statement provides branching control.  It is not a function that evaluates to something that could be assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted the same thing because I use Ruby quite a lot, and that allows you to do that kind of thing. So I created a nuget package called [FluentSwitch](https://github.com/mrstebo/FluentSwitch).