# Defining a variable inside a switch() closure

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case, computer-science, var

Is it possible in C# to define a variable like so?

```
switch(var num = getSomeNum()) {
   case 1: //Do something with num
           break;

   default: break;
}

public static int GetSomeNum() => 3;
```

Comment: Well, what does the compiler tell you?

Comment: Somehow your question is similar to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155772/setting-a-variable-to-a-switchs-result

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a Variable to a Switch's Result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8155772/setting-a-variable-to-a-switchs-result)

Comment: The answer is no.

Comment: I saw you deleted your question on xamarinstudio.xunit. I think you happened to hit a bug (single test case is not properly handled), which I just fixed in a new release, https://github.com/xunit/xamarinstudio.xunit/releases/tag/v0.7.6 You can download the .mpack and manually install it following the readme file, https://github.com/xunit/xamarinstudio.xunit/

Comment: @LexLi hey, I haven't deleted it, I was redirected to a different sub-forum and the issue was resolved there, and the thread closed. Thank you, indeed installing the new release fixed the problem! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) says that

> In C# 6, the match expression must be an expression that returns a
>   value of the following types:
>
> - a char.
> - a string.
> - a bool.
> - an integral value, such as an int or a long.
> - an enum value.
>
> Starting with C# 7, the match expression can be any non-null
>   expression.

To answer your question,

**Yes** you can switch on an int, e.g.

```
int myInt = 3;
switch(myInt)
```

**Yes** you can switch on the result of a method that returns an it, e.g.

```
int GetMyInt() 
{
    // Get my Int
}

switch(GetMyInt())
```

**Yes** you can switch on variable populated with a method result, e.g.

```
int GetMyInt() 
{
    // Get my Int
}

int myInt = GetMyInt();

switch(myInt)
```

**No** you can't do it like that.

Comment: Thanks! I was asking because I saw the microsoft keynote about c# 7 but haven't remembered correctly all the new stuff they introduced and couldn't find anywhere an answer.